# Could someone help me understand the phrase "not for (the) want of trying"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

So..I understand the meaning of the phrase "not for (the) lack of trying" and then I've learned that "not for (the) want of trying" has the same definition.
 But how?! Is there a way to understand how 'want of trying' could mean the same thing as 'lack of trying'? 
(It's like, when I hear 'not for lack of trying', the meaning rings right away in my head, but with 'not for want of trying',  my brain seems to pause and says "...what?")

Comment: *Want* noun. 1. The condition or quality of lacking something usual or necessary: stayed home for want of anything better to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the verb *to want* in the sense of *to wish for*, but in its older sense of *to be lacking in.* The related noun *want* means the same as *lack.*

Comment: I find this use of ***want*** a bit "dated". As [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+for+want+of+trying%2Cnot+for+lack+of+trying%2Cnot+for+want+of+effort%2Cnot+for+lack+of+effort&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20for%20want%20of%20trying%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20for%20lack%20of%20trying%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20for%20want%20of%20effort%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20for%20lack%20of%20effort%3B%2Cc0) shows, *not for **lack** of [effort, opportunity,...]* has overtaken ***want*** in recent decades.

Comment: The verbal use is certainly semi-obsolete, but expressions such as _in want of_ and _for want of a nail_ [see](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+want+of+a+nail) are pretty well-established.

Comment: I'd say [*in **want** of*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+in+want+of%2Cis+in+need+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20in%20want%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20in%20need%20of%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cis%20in%20want%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20in%20need%20of%3B%2Cc0) ***was*** well-established in Victorian times. But as that NGram shows, it was supplanted by *in **need** of* nearly a century and a half ago. Obviously we'd normally just say *He **needs** X* rather than *He's in need of X*, but *He's in **want** of X* is just "odd" to me.